# ion is not a known element - angular language service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created an app in ionic but the angular language service returns this error:

[image]

So my question is simply do I have to disable this extension or is something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue when generating a new component, I added that component to declarations in app.module.ts and that solved the issue.

```
@NgModule({
   // add the component inside declaration
   declarations:[here]
}
```